# What is Java 9's new string implementation?

Tags: java, string, java-9

How are strings implemented in Java 9 under the hood? Is each character stored as one or two bytes?

Comment: Since Java 9 hasn't been released yet, is this behavior officially finalized?

Comment: @DanielPryden - Valid point.  However, this late in the development cycle for Java 9 it is *unlikely* that they will reverse this change.

Comment: @DanielPryden (Java 9 developer here) I concur with Stephen C. The compact strings work is integrated, and it's been well tested and benchmarked. It's not coming out.

Comment: @StuartMarks Just to clarify your last sentence of "It's not coming out" you mean it's not coming out of Java-9 or its not coming out with Java-9? It seems like you mean the former because of your first sentence.

Comment: @A_Arnold A fair point! I meant, it's not going to be removed from Java 9, so it will be delivered along with Java 9 when the whole thing is released.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because most usages of Strings are Latin-1 and only require one byte, Java-9's String will be updated to be implemented under the hood as a byte array with an encoding flag field to note if it is a byte array. If the characters are not Latin-1 and require more than one byte it will be stored as a UTF-16 char array (2 bytes per char) and the flag. See [JEP 254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) .